# How to build just one file with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

For a fast preview, I want to build only one file and not all the project. It is possible with sphinx ?

Recently I do something like :

```sh
sphinx-build -b html documentation/ doc_html
```

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx already uses incremental build by writing output files only for new and changed source files. But before that, full build is needed because Sphinx needs to know where the internal links are pointing and where they are referenced from.